# background animation not setup perfect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, codepen

My CSS animation is not set properly.

Here is a codepen example `[https://codepen.io/Dev_PHioNiX/pen/XWBjrXY][1]`

I have make one example in this I have added 2 label and input box but it's not showing above canvas and also I want that center.

I want to set this background on my login div how can I do this? I have tried but the canvas only showing not the login.

Comment: Please, elaborate on what you are trying to do, how you tried to do it (using which functions did your try to set background, for example), what were you expecting to happen, and what happened. People should not have to read your code to understand what you were trying to do, and how. Especially not if to read that code they have to follow a link (which is impossible here, anyway, since the link is broken. But even if it weren't, you are suppose to include the minimal code needed to understand the question directly in the question).

Comment: i an trying to familiar with stack overflow environment. sorry for any miss information. @chrslg

Comment: Hi, if you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it should help you put a runnable snippet into your question - not into an external codepen please. And please explain what isn't working.

Comment: as per your comment i have made one simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
```

remove this form from canvas tag and place into  this div and add little bit css for center it.

```
div.btnbg {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  top: 30%;
}
```

using this css you can center your form.

Comment: it's worked thanks. @Akshay Sorathiya